# Unknown column 'price_index.min_price' when i search for some product

Tags: database, error, magento-1

When I make some search on my store for some product I keep getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'price_index.min_price' in 'field list', query was: `` SELECT
>   FLOOR(((price_index.min_price +(e.min_price*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 4
>   THEN       0.2300 WHEN 5 THEN       0.2300  ELSE 0 END)) * 1) / 10) +
>   1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_index_price`
>   AS `e`  INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_result` AS `search_result` ON
>   search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id='33' 
>   INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON
>   cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND
>   cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '3' WHERE (
>   e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = 0) AND ((e.min_price
>   +(e.min_price*CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 4 THEN       0.2300 WHEN 5 THEN       0.2300  ELSE 0 END)) IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY `range` ``

Before was working, I didn't upgrade anything... In database I searched for the  table name "`price_index`" and I didn't found it, but I guess that the query is made internally so I can't fix it... I already was checking the file `Price.php` but I can't find any solution to fix this...

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php

Any Solution?

Edit: Already reindex all things and still the same...

Edit2: Is the problem from the database or from the magento code?

Comment: You dump uploaded to database whith error, you can use repairtools for magento database repair

Answer (score 1):

I faced the issue a while back I remember I **fixed the issue by reindexing everything.**

Comment: You're popping up in LQP review. Shouldn't this be a comment? ;)

Comment: @7ochem well yeah not sure but as that's how I fixed that issue when I faced it I posted it as an answer ^^